# The type Response.Response builder is not visible

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am writing a RESTful service in java, but when I try using `Resource` class, the following error is shown: `The type Response.Response builder is not visible`. I don't understand what the problem might be, since I have already imported the needed jars and configured the classpath. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing the issue?

This is the method I am using to get a list of events, and I am getting the error wherever `Response` is used:

```
@GET 
@Path("/active")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getActiveEvents() {
    ArrayList<Event> list = EventSetup.getActiveEvents();
    if(list.size() > 0) return Response.status(200).entity(list).build();
    else return Response.status(404).entity("NULL").build();
}
```

Comment: What REST API are you using? JAX-RS? Please include an example of the code that generates the error.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken yes, I am using JAX-RS. I have edited the question and added code example, but it is not just this method, but all the other methods in which `Response` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. All the `jar` files included in the project need to be in the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder, or `Eclipse` won't see them and will create an error.

Answer (score 0):

The code you listed is correct. As you specified JSON as output format, JAX-RS will serialize the result object (`ArrayList<Event>`) using an object mapper, usually `Jackson`.

I assume the error occured during serialization.

- are there any **custom or special serializers** used (in the configuration of the ObjectMapper, or as Jackson annotations)? It's possible that one of these serializers make use of the Response builder, so they may be to blame.
- did you import **the correct** `Response` **class** (`javax.ws.rs.core.Response`)? You might have accidentally imported a `Response` class from another package.

The **stack trace** is immensly helpful to locate the source of the Exception - please always include the stack trace when asking for help with exceptions you're getting.